# How do proponents of sola fide explain Titus 1:16?

Tags: exegesis, soteriology, baptist, sola-fide, titus

Evangelicals believe that faith alone establishes your salvation.  How do they resolve **Titus 1:16**?

> They profess that they know God; but in works they deny him, being abominable, and disobedient, and unto every good work reprobate.

While I understand that evangelicals don't directly recommend doing abominable, disobedient and reprobating good work - they also generally don't believe that you can lose your salvation, which this passage seems to imply.

Comment: I've edited the question for broader applicability. The accepted answer still applies. Feel free to re-edit or let me know if this is an unwelcome change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Laying the Groundwork

### The Transformation of Salvation

It is important to note that, according to the Bible, the following things occur at the moment of salvation by faith alone:

- We, who were **once dead**, are **made alive** in Christ:

  > When you were dead in your transgressions and the uncircumcision of your flesh, He made you alive together with Him, having forgiven us all our transgressions.  (Colossians 2:13)
- We, who were once **in the dominion of darkness**, are **brought into the kingdom of Jesus**

  > For He rescued us from the domain of darkness, and transferred us to the kingdom of His beloved Son, 14 in whom we have redemption, the forgiveness of sins.  (Colossians 1:13-14)
- We, who were once **alienated from God**, **hostile to God** (or **enemies of God**) have now become **the children of God** by virtue of a new birth:

  > And although you were formerly alienated and hostile in mind, engaged in evil deeds" (Colossians 1:21)
  >
  > But as many as received Him, to them He gave the right to become children of God, even to those who believe in His name, who were born, not of blood nor of the will of the flesh nor of the will of man, but of God.  (John 1:12-13)
- We, who were one **sinful**, are now a **holy nation**, **made righteous** and renewed in our spirits:

  > But you are a chosen race, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, a people for God’s own possession, so that you may proclaim the excellencies of Him who has called you out of darkness into His marvelous light.  (1 Peter 2:9)
  >
  > For all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God, 24 being justified [declared righteous] as a gift by His grace through the redemption which is in Christ Jesus.  (Romans 3:23-24)
  >
  > Do not lie to one another, since you laid aside the old self with its evil practices, 10 and have put on the new self who is being renewed to a true knowledge according to the image of the One who created him.  (Colossians 3:9-10)

### The Impact of the Transformation

So, at the moment of salvation, a very significant transformation has occurred.  We are changed at the very core of our beings so that our desires have changed and our spirits are now alive.  Indeed, we have the Holy Spirit Himself indwelling us:

> Or do you not know that your body is a temple of the Holy Spirit who is in you, whom you have from God, and that you are not your own? (1 Corinthians 6:19)

What this results in is a drastic change in desires.  Someone who has truly put their faith in Christ should have new desires, and their salvation should naturally result in a change in their actions.

So, you should see the impact of their faith in the works that they do, but it is not a salvation by works.  Put another way, we believe that salvation is by faith alone, but a genuine faith will inevitably result in a change in actions and behavior.  If you observe no change in desires or actions, then it is cause to doubt the genuineness of the faith.

## Titus 1:16

From an evangelical perspective, the verse you cited is not speaking about those who truly believe in Christ, but whose actions have failed to change.  Rather, it is speaking of those whose faith is not genuine and whose actions reveal this to be true.  Jesus Himself indicated that "by their fruits you will know them" in Matthew 7:16.

## Conclusion

So, if you observe someone professing faith in Christ who is doing abominable things without shame or repentance, we should not conclude that this is someone who has truly put his or her faith in Christ, been brought out of the kingdom of darkness into the kingdom of light, made a new creation, forgiven, cleansed, made righteous, made alive and indwelt by the Holy Spirit of God, but who is failing to reflect in any way the life of a Christian.  Rather we should conclude that no change has really taken place and, as a result, no true faith has been exercised.

Comment: While most "Evangelical" denominations would give the answer in your last paragraph, there are indeed some (particularly among Baptists) that teach a version of Once Saved Always Saved that says these people are saved and can basically do anything and will never lose their salvation, only lose rewards.

Comment: @davidbrainerd I agree that they can do anything they want, but my position is that a true believer will have different "wants".  Thus, their fruit will reveal whether or not they are truly following Christ.

Comment: An undue emphasis on faith alone that makes it sound like faith can ever actually be alone, however, has a tendency to produce those who are not truly following Christ but just looking for a quick fix, which I think was the point of the OP.

Answer (score -2):

James  1;22

But  be  ye  doers  of  the  word,  and  not  hearers  only,  deceiving  your  own  selves.

James  2;19,20,21,22,23,26

a. 19  Thou  believest  that  there  is  one  God,  thou  doest  well:  the  devils  also  believe  and  tremble.

b. 20  But  wilt  thou  know,  O  vain  man,  that  faith  without  works  is  dead?

c. 21  Was  not  Abraham  our  father  justified  by  works,  when  he  had  offered  Isaac  his  son  upon  the  alter?

d. 22  Seest  thou  how  faith  wrought  with  his  works,  and  by  works  was  faith  made  perfect?

e.  23 And  the  scripture  was  ful-filled  which  saith,  Abraham  believed  God,  and  it  was  imputed  unto  him  for  righteousness:  and  he  was  called  the  Friend  of  God.

f.  26 For  as  the  body  without  the  spirit  is  dead,  so  faith  without  works  is  dead  also.

Salvation  is  conditional!

Comment: How do you mean salvation is conditional exsactly? Because you did not sight salvation scriptures and also in relation to at least John 3.

Comment: Matthew 22;39  And the second is like unto it, Thou shalt love thy neighbour as thyself.

Comment: Was that suppose to answer my question?

Comment: Matther 22;39 is one half of the great commandment Jesus   gave the disciples. It is incomplete, as is Titus 1;16 A careful examination of Titus 1 should reveal your answer.

Comment: Our  faith  has to be manifested in action; submission  of our will,  turn from our ways, and follow the examples of  Jesus.  Not  only hearers and thinkers, but doers.

Comment: I know what my answer is, I teach this stuff, I want to know your answer and how you have come about your idea. Thats kinda what S.E. is about...not posting and saying go look it up. And Im not talking about our works being evidence of our faith or it is dead. I guess Im asking you to be a thinker,  de ready with a reason for your belief as scripture says.  How,  in your opinion,  is the free gift of salvation conditional?  ( Jesus gave incomplete instruction?!?)

Comment: John 3;3  Jesus answered and said unto him,  verily, verily, I say unto thee, except a man be born again, he cannot see the kingdom of God.   Unless one is truly converted,  there is no salvation. The conversion experience requires submission and change.   James 1;22  But be ye doers of the word, and not hearers only, deceiving your own selves.

Comment: Yes, I understand John 3 as it in its entirely, but being born again is referenced to our first birth, what did you have involved in that?  Nothing you had no say, hense the 2nd birth that we have no involvement in either. Thats why the analogy, the only thing that we might be able to lay claim to is the "believe" part of John 5 but even then our belief/faith in that is not ours Ephesians 2:8 God saved you by his grace when you believed. And you can't take credit for this; it is a gift from God. So even with this "condition" it is God that does it not us. I won't even go into Romans 5.

Comment: James 1:22 has nothing to do with salvation, it is only the evidence of the changed life as in James2:14,26 teaches...and further on in James 1:24 for once he has looked at himself and gone away, he has immediately forgotten what kind of person he was....meaning not saved.

Comment: I take, absolutely, no credit  for my repentance or salvation. They are gifts from God. However, had I  refused to submit my will, God  would have  allowed me to reap whatever I sowed. God does not force submission.In Exodus;14;15  And the Lord said to Moses, Wherefore criest thou to me?  speak unto the children of Israel, that they go forward. There was no question as to their belief, only that they move forward. Our walk with God requires action. Nothing less.

Comment: So then salvation is not conditional and not of ourselves, john 3 states all we have to do is believe and even that is a gift fron God. Our walk or faith requires works or its dead but our salvation requires nothing because as you stated it is a gift. After all we are dead in our sins and what can a dead man do? I just wanted to work out what appeard to be a conflict in your answer. And by doing so you have exsplained salvation us not conditional.

Comment: Also Abraham was not just justfied by works alone...Gal 3:6 "Abraham believed God, and God counted him as righteous because of his faith." And Genesis 15:6 And he believed in the LORD; and he counted it to him for righteousness. Romans4 … 2 For if Abraham was justified by works, he has something to boast about, but not before God. 3 For what does the Scripture say? "ABRAHAM BELIEVED GOD, AND IT WAS CREDITED AS RIGHTEOUSNESS." 4 to the one who works, his wage is not credited as a favor,the one who does not work, but believes in Him who justifies the ungodly, his faith is credited as rightness..

Comment: I believe I understand you completely, there must be belief! I agree! However, to vaslidate one's belief there should be acompanying movement or action. In Matthew 10;28 Jesus  said; thou hast answered right: this DO and thou shalt live.

Comment: Right...but its not a condition for salvation....its a result of a changed life, proof if you will otherwise it was just covering a base...but the fact that we do is even a gift from him as scripture teaches...salvation is not based on works...so anytime we include something that shows we, under our own power, have done something it becomes a "work" we have done...so if we are required to do something in and of ourself it becomes a work thus not a gift...god even takes credit for our belief ...thus there is nothing we have done in securing our salvation.

Comment: And you are actually incorrect, it is Luke 10:28 but the verse must be considerd in its entire context of the parable of the Good Samaritan ; 25 And a lawyer stood up and put Him to the test, saying, "Teacher, what shall I do to inherit eternal life?" 26 And He said to him, "What is written in the Law? How does it read to you?" 27 And he answered, "YOU SHALL LOVE THE LORD YOUR GOD WITH ALL YOUR HEART, AND WITH ALL YOUR SOUL, AND WITH ALL YOUR STRENGTH, AND WITH ALL YOUR MIND; AND YOUR NEIGHBOR AS YOURSELF."… and this not till after we believe,John 3,because you know this is not all.

Comment: I assume the lawyer wsa not born again. John 3;16 For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life. Belief is necessary.  John 3;5 Jesus answered , verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born of water and of the Spirit he cannot  enter into the kingdom of God. John 3;23 And John also was baptizing in Aeon near to Salim, because there was much water there: and they came and were baptized. This is the action, not works, because the Holy Spirit caused the action.

Comment: One could not be born again till after the cross, till then onesfaith was counted as rightiousness, and that faith was not of ourselves but of God so no man could boast. Batism is our outward action of our salvation.  It was not the salvation itself. I.E. if someone believes then dies b4 baptism does this mean he is not saved? Of course not. Likewise the theif on the cross, all he did was believe.So belief is all one needs, it is why, while all baptism scripture surrounds salvation,not all salvation scripture is surronded by baptism. Not a condition for salvation.Salvation is not conditional.

Comment: Belief is the only thing nessasry...and that is what God gives us...if anything added that we have to do makes it work on our part...and salvation is not by works least any man boast.

Comment: How can God use you if you never do anything?

Comment: @moderators: This answer and comment thread is well worth preserving in chat, so that iron can sharpen iron, and some content from the discussion can then be posted as questions and answers, properly backed up with references to recognized church leaders. Only those subjects meeting site standards for question and on-topic answer should be posted as Q and A. It might be best to put some initial restrictions on other members posting to the chat room.